# MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA deprecated, how fix this?

Tags: android, pdf, storage, external, mediastore

I would like to replace function below because DATA is deprecated

It's necessary to list only path in the base directory

If I using "MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID", I can return Uri Lists, but I lost external storage path

The goal is to open the PDF viewer on a PDF file that is in "Documents" (in external storage)

Can you help me please?

```
public static Vector<String> getFilesListInExternalStorage(Context context, String mimeType, String baseDirectory) {
        Vector<String> list = new Vector<>();
        Uri collection;
        String selection = "";
        String[] selectionArgs = {""};

        final String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
        };

        final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";

        if(baseDirectory==null || baseDirectory.isEmpty())
        {
            selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType};
        }
        else
        {
            selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ? AND "+ MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA + " like ? ";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{mimeType, "%"+baseDirectory+"%"};
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
        }else{
            collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        }

        try (Cursor cursor = Objects.requireNonNull(context).getContentResolver().query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)) {
            assert cursor != null;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
                do {
                    list.add((cursor.getString(columnData)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Thank you very much

Have a nice day

Loïc

Comment: If your app put the document in `Documents/`, you may be able to use `FileProvider`. If your app did not put the document in `Documents/`, you will not have access to it, whether using `MediaStore` or anything else, on Android 11 and higher.

Comment: yes I used File Provider, add in AndroidManifest and using it in Intent

Answer (score 0):

```
 try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(collection, Constants.FILE_PROJECTION, sb.toString(), strArr2, sort)) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
            do {
                String path = cursor.getString(columnData);
                File file = new File(path);

                if (file.exists()) {
                    fileList.add(new File(cursor.getString(columnData)));
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return fileList;
```

try this

Comment: hello, please can you tell me how I should affect "sb", "strArr2" and "sort" please?

Comment: strarr :    public static final String[] FILE_TYPE_ALL = {"doc", "docx","pdf","ppt","pptx","xls","xlsx","xltx","txt"}; 
           https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vimalcvs/All-Document-Reader/main/app/src/main/java/alldocumentreader/vimal/office/viewer/filereader/units/Utils.java?token=GHSAT0AAAAAAB2Q6BJJ47R5IXLNPZ45TFR2Y3KUYLQ

Comment: hello,  sorry but I no possible to open link. best regards